# Mysql query "Unknown column 'gender' in field list"

Tags: mysql

I'm using the query below

```
INSERT INTO characters (name, userid, world_id, face, hair, skin, geneder, str, dex, `int`, luk) VALUES ('" & MySqlHelper.EscapeString(name) & "', " & mID & ", " & mChosenWorld & ", " & face & ", " & (hair + haircolor) & ", " & skin & ", " & 0 & ", " & str & ", " & dex & ", " & int & ", " & luk & ")"
```

but it is giving me the error : `Unknown column 'gender' in the field list`.

Comment: My guess is that the real error message is `Unknown column 'geneder'` because you misspelled it in the column list.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is not enough information to rule out a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You used "geneder" instead of "gender", correct it.

If it still doesn't work, post your table structure.